# getting error : TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement the inline edit but i am getting an error :

```
TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

$('#editbox').live('blur',function(){
```

My code :

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){



        $('td.edit').click(function(e){

                        var $target = $(e.target);
            if($target.is('#editbox')){
                return;
            }                   
                                        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                                        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');

                                        $(this).addClass('ajax');
                                        $(this).html('<input id="editbox"  size="10" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');

                                        $('#editbox').select();
                         }

                          );

        $('td.edit').keydown(function(event){

   arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );


                                     if(event.which == 13)
                                     { 

                                        $.ajax({    type: "POST",
                                                    url:"supplier/update.php",
                                                    data: "value="+$('.ajax input').val()+"&rowid="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1],
                                                    success: function(data){
                                                         $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                                                         $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                                                    }});
                                     }

                                  }

                          );


        $('#editbox').live('blur',function(){

                                     $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                                     $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                                    });

    });

    </script>
```

html:

Comment: See here https://api.jquery.com/category/removed/ and check out http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `on` instead of `live`

```
$('body').on('blur', '#editbox', function(){}
```

[.live()  vs  .on()](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are using a jquery version >= `1.9`.

[**`.live()`**](https://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated in the version `1.7` and it was removed in the version `1.9`

For the version >= 1.9 you have to use [**`.on()`**](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to achieve the same result.

Try,

```
 $('#staticParent').on('blur' ,'#editbox' ,function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

.live() is depreciate in 1.9 or + version

Replaced by .on()

https://api.jquery.com/on/